# how to use $lookup stage in java with spring data mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Up to last version of spring i have seen lot of stack over flow questions which shows there is no support for this operation in spring-data-mongodb is there any support for this operation in new spring-data-mongodb 1.10.0

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "inventory",
              localField: "item",
              foreignField: "sku",
              as: "inventory_docs"
            }
       }
    ])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lookup support has been there since 1.9 version.

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                                   from("inventory").
                                   localField("item").
                                   foreignField("sku").
                                   as("inventory_docs");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation);
List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, "orders", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Comment: thanks a lot its working perfectly and please help me how to add criteria to it

Comment: You are welcome . Please create a separate question with complete information and add what you have tried and someone will help you.

Comment: Thanks i just solved it by checking spring documentation

Comment: Hi .. I am fetching all states based on country id from the mongodb database. 

db.country.aggregate([{ $lookup: { from: "state", localField: "countryId", foreignField: "countryId", as: "address"}}])

My following code in java ,however, returns an empty list .
LookupOperation lookUpOprn = LookupOperation.newLookup()
    .from("state")
    .localField("countryId")
    .foreignField("countryId")
    .as("address");
 List<BasicDBObject> list =  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "country", BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();

Can you please help

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953464/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-with-other-collection-as-well/61954736?noredirect=1#61954736