# Aggregation lookup not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am running the following aggregation lookup query in spring but it doesn't seems to output the same result as one i run in mongo shell. I am guessing mongo shell knows that from:"testModel" collection exists but how do spring know "testModel" exists as we are only pass strings in  Aggregation.lookup("testModel"). I can run all other stages fine for example match or project..

```
// code running in Mongo Shell
db.demoModel.aggregate([{
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "testModel",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "makeId",
        as: "cool"
      }
 }]
)

// code from spring
    public List<DemoModel> getSomeAutos() throws Exception {

    LookupOperation lookupStage = Aggregation.lookup(
           "testModel",
           "_id",
           "makeId",
            "cool"

    );

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupStage);

    List<DemoModel> demomode =  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "demoModel", DemoModel.class).getMappedResults();

    return demomode;

}

// DemoModel.class
public class DemoModel {
@Id
private String id;
private String value;
private String label;



public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}
}

//Mongo demoModel Collection
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4b"), 
 "value" : "Mitsubishi", 
 "label" : "Mitsubishi"
}
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4c"), 
 "value" : "BMW", 
 "label" : "BMW"
}

// Mongo testModel Collection

{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee393b80c346266f25aba"), 
"make" : "Mitsubishi", 
"label" : "3000GT", 
"value" : "3000GT",
"makeId" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4b")
}
 { 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee393b80c346266f25af8"), 
  "make" : "BMW", 
  "label" : "Alpina A2", 
  "value" : "Alpina A2",  
  "makeId" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4c")
}
```

// Response i am getting

```
[
  {
    "id": "5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4b",
    "value": "Mitsubishi",
    "label": "Mitsubishi"
  },
  {
    "id": "5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4c",
    "value": "BMW",
    "label": "BMW"
 }
]
```

// expected response in this format

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4b"), 
  "value" : "Mitsubishi", 
  "label" : "Mitsubishi", 
  "cool" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a8ee393b80c346266f25aba"), 
        "make" : "Mitsubishi", 
        "label" : "3000GT", 
        "value" : "3000GT", 
        "makeId" : ObjectId("5a8ee0d815dc17aa32f90f4b")
    }]
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use $lookup stage in java with spring data mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42452764/how-to-use-lookup-stage-in-java-with-spring-data-mongodb)

Comment: Should work. It may be failing when it is mapping to DemoModel. Can you run  `Document demomode = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "demoModel", DemoModel.class).getRawResults();` to see the mongo response before mapping ? Also add DemoModel to the post if you can.

Comment: mongo response is {{serverUsed=null, ok=1.0, result=[]}} when i used .getRawResults()

Comment: Hi @Veeram - i've added the full code. Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve it ? I thought I saw an answer from you. Couple of things based on previous comment and post updates. You are missing mapping for "cool" field. You get empty result array from server which tells me there are other aggregation stages before or after lookup stage.

Comment: @Veeram - yes, i manage to resolve it. you're correct i was missing cool field in DemoModel class. Thanks for your help. Kam.